# changing global variable in another python file

Tags: python-2.7, global-variables

I am planning to modify global variable in another python file by importing the file. The new file is seems to have modified the global variable. However when global variable is accessed by calling a function within the original class it is still not modified. How can I achieve this? For example, `base_file.py` is defined as following:

```
CONFIG_DICT = {'Name1': 'Value1'}

def print_config():
   for name, val in CONFIG_DICT.iteritems():
      print 'Inside print_config - Name:%s and Value:%s' % (name, val)
```

`new_file.py` is defined as following:

```
import base_file as bf

def update_config():
   for name, val in bf.CONFIG_DICT.iteritems():
      print 'Before modification inside update_config - Name:%s and Value:%s' % (name, val)
   bf.CONFIG_DICT = {}
   bf.CONFIG_DICT['Name2'] = 'Value2'
   for name, val in bf.CONFIG_DICT.iteritems():
      print 'After modification inside update_config - Name:%s and Value:%s' % (name, val)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   bf.print_config()
   update_config()
   bf.print_config()
```

The output of running `new_file.py` is as follows:

```
Inside print_config - Name:Name1 and Value:Value1
Before modification inside update_config - Name:Name1 and Value:Value1
After modification inside update_config - Name:Name2 and Value:Value2
###########################################################
# How Can I change this so that this yields Name2, Value2?#
###########################################################
Inside print_config - Name:Name1 and Value:Value1
```